# I understand how to use template with script but not with server controls

Tags: kendo-ui

Now what I am trying to do is a hybrid or server controls and javascript. I think kendo server controls are elegant.
As you can see I am desparately trying to find how to access editable property in the grid but have no luck.I thought it would be

```
 var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
 grid.editable.template = function () { kendo.template($("#MyTemplate").html()) };
```

The idea is that when a user click on the edit button they get to see #MyTemplate instead of kendo default html version of it. Perhaps, I need to go in a different direction please guide me.

## Here is my full code just for reference.

```
 @model IEnumerable<Msh.Intranet.Models.ApiAdFileDisplayGridModel>
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="myTemplate">           
            <input data-bind="value: Id" name="Id"/>
        </script>
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Id).Visible(false);
        columns.Bound(p => p.FileName).Visible(false);
        columns.Bound(p => p.FormNumber);
        columns.Bound(p => p.FormTitle);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Class);
        columns.Bound(p => p.SecondaryCategory).Title("Category") ;
        columns.Bound(p => p.RevisionDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
        columns.Command(c =>
        {

            c.Edit();
            c.Destroy();
        });

    })
    .Selectable()
     .Groupable()
     .Pageable()
     .Filterable()
     //.Sortable()
           .ToolBar(tools =>
      {
          tools.Create();
      })
      .Editable(editor => editor.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
     .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()

        //this tells kendo I am the primary key
            .Model(model => 
            { 
                model.Id(p => p.Id);
                model.Field(p => p.RevisionDate);
            })
        .Read(read => read.Url(@Url.Action("ApiAdFileDisplayGrid","api",null,null)).Type(HttpVerbs.Get))
        .Create(create=>create.Url(@Url.Action("ApiAdFileDisplayGrid","api",null,null)).Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
        .Update(update=>update.Url(@Url.Action("ApiAdFileDisplayGrid","api",null,null)).Type(HttpVerbs.Put))
        .Destroy(destroy=>destroy.Url(@Url.Action("ApiAdFileDisplayGrid","api",null,null)).Type(HttpVerbs.Delete))
    )
)
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");

        //grid.bind("change", function () {
        //    alert("Change ");
        //});

        grid.bind("dataBound", function (data) {
            alert("dataBound");

        });

        grid.bind("edit", function (e) {

            if (e.model.isNew()) {

                //create
                alert("new");


            } else {

                //edit
                alert("edit");

            }

        })

    // WebAPI needs the ID of the entity to be part of the URL e.g. PUT /api/Product/80
    grid.dataSource.transport.options.update.url = function (data) {
        var baseUrl = "@Url.Content("~/api/ApiAdFileDisplayGrid/")" +data.Id;
        return baseUrl;
    }

    // WebAPI needs the ID of the entity to be part of the URL e.g. DELETE /api/Product/80
    grid.dataSource.transport.options.destroy.url = function(data) {
        var baseUrl = "@Url.Content("~/api/ApiAdFileDisplayGrid/")" + data.Id;
        return baseUrl;
    }
        grid.editable.template = function () { kendo.template($("#MyTemplate").html()) };
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To customize the editor you should use the MVC Editor templates engine. Follow the approach in [this](http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/mvc/grid/custom-popup-editor.aspx) code library.

Comment: But how do i access javascript properties that the kendo asp mvc html helpers create.

Comment: I just review the editor template way. That is genius thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread in kendo site which give me an alternative to my method of doing templates:
http://www.kendoui.com/forums/mvc/grid/new-client-details-template.aspx#2427170

However, it would be interesting to see how to interact with the javascript objects the kendo html helpers create.